# Condição WHERE não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter, mysqli

Estou tentando colocar uma condição em uma função e não esta dando certo...
tentei colocar essa condição mas não funcionou `$this->db->where('idUser =', $this->session->userdata('id'));`
Geralmente todas condição faço como o código abaixo, mas somente este que não deu certo.

```
function get($table, $fields, $where = '', $perpage = 0, $start = 0, $one = false, $array = 'array')
{

    $this->db->select($fields.', clientes.nomeCliente, clientes.idClientes');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->limit($perpage, $start);
    $this->db->join('clientes', 'clientes.idClientes = '.$table.'.clientes_id');
    $this->db->order_by('idVendas', 'desc');
    $this->db->where('idUser =', $this->session->userdata('id'));

    if ($where) {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Utiliza `print_r($this->db->last_query());` para você ter o `SQL` dessa consulta e verifica se ela estar correta e se funciona diretamente no banco.

Comment: Talvez por conta do `join` você precise especificar qual a tabela do campo `idUser`, por exemplo: `$this->db->where('nomeDaTabela.idUser =', $this->session->userdata('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Nessa primeira linha:

```
$this->db->select($fields.', clientes.nomeCliente, clientes.idClientes');
```

Aquele "ponto" e aquela "aspa simples" antes da vírgula, não estão errados?

O ponto não deveria existir ali, e a aspa deveria ser aberta em clientes.nomeCliente.

E no WHERE

```
$this->db->where('idUser =', $this->session->userdata('id'));
```

Tenta remover o sinal de "=".

Answer (score -1):

Só uma pergunta é o framework `codeigniter` que esta usar, se estiver acho que ai  na sua condição:

```
$this->db->where('idUser', $this->session->userdata('id'));
```

No `codeigniter` ou usa o( `=` ) ou ( `,`  ) quando quiser usar a função de igualmente entre dois valores.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->where('idUser',$this->session->userdata('id'));
```

Comment: No codeigniter você pode inserir um operador de comparação junto com o primeiro parâmetro.